# Evaluate truth value of formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am not sure about this question?

Domain = {1, 2}

Assignment of constants: a = 1 and b = 2

Assignment of functions: f(1) = 2 and f(2) = 1

Assignment for predicate P: P(1, 1) = T; P(1, 2) = T; P(2, 1) = F; P(2, 2) = F

Evaluate the truth value of following formulas in the above interpretation:

a. P(a, f(a)) ∧ P(b, f(b))

b. (∀a)(∃b)P(b, a)

c. (∀a)(∀b)(P(a, b) → P(f(a), f(b))

Comment: What have you tried? Since $a,b$ are constants, you shouldn't be using those as variables in b. and c. Do you even understand the question?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all, its right from the homework sheet, I haven't changed anything

Comment: my teacher says to consider x=a, y=b -- not sure what this question is asking though so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

**a)** $$P(a,  f(a)) \land P(b, f(b)) \equiv P(1,2) \land P(2,1) \equiv T \land F \equiv F$$

**b)** $\forall a \exists b\; P(b,a)$?

It is true. Why? Because, for all $a$, exists $b$ such as $P(b,a)$ is true:

- If $a = 1$, then $b = 1$ verifies $P(b,a)$.
- If $a = 2$, then $b = 1$ verifies $P(b,a)$.

**c)** $\forall a\;\forall b \;\Big(P(a,b) \to P\big(f(a), f(b)\big)\Big)$.

Take $a = 1$ and $b = 1$ and you will see that the statement is false (counterexample):
$$P(a,b) \equiv T  \textbf{ does not implies } P\big(f(a), f(b)\big) \equiv P\big(f(1),f(1)\big) \equiv P(2,2) \equiv F$$

Comment: @user307772 The first step would be to look up the definitions of $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Comment: so what exactly did you do here? you substituted in part a). in part b) how do those verify the same thing if they are different. in part c) how did you get f(a), f(b) to both equal f(1), f(1) ???

Comment: @BrianO yes I know, for all and for some, at least one.